# Template list creation C#

Tags: c#, templates, linked-list

```
public static void GenerateRandomd<T>(D_List<T> list, int size, Random rand)
    {
        if (list is D_List<int>)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                list.Push_Back(rand.Next(0, 10000));
        }
        else if (list is D_List<string>)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                list.Push_Back(Gen_rand_string(rand));
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                list.Push_Back(rand.NextDouble());
        }
    }
```

Hello! Is it possible to implement something like this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please clarify (preferably using *words*) what you want to achieve? It is indeed possible to get code shown in the post to compile... (I.e. by having generic `Push_Back<T>` along with non-generic `Push_Back(double)`) but that's probably not what you want to achieve...

Comment: Side note: are you looking for "template" (as in code-generation at compile time using something like T4) or "generics" (which code in the questions uses)? Using wrong tags is expected to bring answers you are not interested in.

Comment: If I try to execute this code, it will return an error "cannot convert from "int" to "T"". Is it possible to avoid this somehow, while leaving the assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to cast `list` variable with [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching):

```
public static void GenerateRandomd<T>(D_List<T> list, int size, Random rand)
{
    switch (list)
    {
        case D_List<int> il:
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                il.Push_Back(rand.Next(0, 10000));
            break;
        case D_List<string> sl:
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                sl.Push_Back(Gen_rand_string(rand));
            break;
        default:
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                (list as D_List<double>).Push_Back(rand.NextDouble());
    }
}
```

Or you can cast it directly in your code:

```
public static void GenerateRandomd<T>(D_List<T> list, int size, Random rand)
{
    if (list is D_List<int>)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            (list as DList<int>).Push_Back(rand.Next(0, 10000)); // cast variable to the DList<int> at each step of the cyclecast
    }
    else if (list is D_List<string>)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            (list is D_List<string>).Push_Back(Gen_rand_string(rand));
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            (list is D_List<double>).Push_Back(rand.NextDouble());
    }
}
```

If default scenario implies a different type so you may implement non-generic `Push_Back(double value)` method for `D_List`.

Comment: First variant is the best! Спасибо большое!